# reactJS components should pop into the view once reaching end point of the current component or div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {isExplainers:false, isVideoExp:false, isOurVideo:false }
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }
   componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
   componentWillUnMount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll=()=>{
    const height = document.getElementById('explainers').clientHeight;
      const height1 = document.getElementById('video').clientHeight;
    console.log("explainers"+height);
    console.log("home"+height1)
    const explainer = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.explainer);
    const home = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.home);
    if(home.scrollTop === explainer.offsetTop) { 
       this.setState({ isExplainers : true });
    }
  }
  ourVideoScroll=()=>{
    const ourVideo = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.ourVideo);
    const explainer = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.explainer);
    if(explainer.scrollTop === ourVideo.offsetTop) { 
       this.setState({isOurVideo:true});
    }
   }
  render() {
    const explainersClass = this.state.isExplainers ? "explainerAfter" : "explainer";
     // const creationClass = this.state.isVideoExp ? "videoCreationAfter" : "videoCreation";
     const ourVideoClass = this.state.isOurVideo ? "videoContainerAfter" : "videoContainer";
    return (

      <div className="App">
      <Home id="home" ref={ref => this.home = ref} onScroll = {this.handleScroll}/>
      <div id="explainers" className={explainersClass} ref={ref => this.explainer = ref} onScroll={this.ourVideoScroll}><Explainers /></div>
      <div id="video" className={ ourVideoClass } ref={ref => this.ourVideo = ref}> <Video /></div>
      <CreateMore />
      <Services/>
      <Animated />
      <Clients/>
      <Footer /> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

There are 7-8 components which should load only when the user reaches the end point of the current div or component how can I achieve this?
This can be done with the help of jQuery but I'm not interested in using that?

Comment: You can try [`react-waypoint`](https://github.com/brigade/react-waypoint).

Comment: What are you asking? Are these 7-8 components in your code above?

Comment: yes all those in jsx tags are components